# What is a 'manifest' when dealing with Reg-Free-Com?

Tags: interop, embed, manifest

I've been told to create a 'manifest' to achieve Reg-Free-Com between a VB6 .EXE and a .NET DLL.

What is a 'manifest' in this context?

What does it mean to 'embed' a manifest?

Answer (score 0):

From: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973913.aspx#rfacomwalk_topic2

*Registration-free COM uses manifest to refer to text files with the .manifest extension containing XML, which either defines the identity of an assembly (assembly manifest), together with the binding and activation details of its classes, or defines the identity of an application (application manifest), together with one or more assembly identity references.*

To 'embed' a manifest means the text information is embedded in the dll as a Win32 resource rather than sitting on disk as a standalone text file.